# restful api get not work，but scan can work

Tags: ignite

anybody know why restful api scan has data

http://127.0.0.1:8080/ignite?cmd=qryscanexe&pageSize=5&cacheName=contact

result
{
"successStatus": 0,
"error": null,
"sessionToken": null,
"response": {
"items": [
{
"key": {
"id": 703896957108224
},
"value": {
"mergedId": null,
"priority": 0,
"identities": [
{
"id": "7",
"type": "idCard",
"dateCreated": 1652932875433,
"lastUpdated": 1652932875433
}
],
"followerIds": [],
"contactType": "LEADER",
"dateCreated": 1652932875433,
"lastUpdated": 1652932875433
}
}
],
"last": true,
"queryId": 2,
"fieldsMetadata": [
{
"schemaName": null,
"typeName": null,
"fieldName": "key",
"fieldTypeName": null
},
{
"schemaName": null,
"typeName": null,
"fieldName": "value",
"fieldTypeName": null
}
]
}
}.

but get command no result.

[http://127.0.0.1:8080/ignite?cacheName=contact&cmd=get&keyType=ContactKey&key={"id":703896957108224}](http://127.0.0.1:8080/ignite?cacheName=contact&cmd=get&keyType=ContactKey&key=%7B%22id%22:703896957108224%7D)

result
{
"successStatus": 0,
"affinityNodeId": "ee5e4d0d-5c91-4b9d-b68f-5dfac2f45908",
"error": null,
"sessionToken": null,
"response": null
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Ignite REST [supports](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/restapi#data-types) Java built-in types for get/put operations. But it should be possible to implement a custom [serialization](https://www.gridgain.com/sdk/ee/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/ConnectorConfiguration.html#getMessageInterceptor--) if needed. In general it's much better to use Ignite thin [clients](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/thin-clients/getting-started-with-thin-clients), it's more functional than REST.

Comment: Yes, the code uses Java Thin Client, but we testers want to see cache type data through the REST API, because Ignite doesn't have a client to look at cache data

Comment: i found reason。you are right，i implement Externalizable。then it is ok